# NetBeans settings for the same code

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I have a small problem with my c/c++ code. I have two absolutely identical code to be run at NetBeans at two different laptop. One in ubuntu, one in xubuntu. I could not run the code in my Ubuntu environment, with the fail message

```
"RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 2s; user: 20ms; system: 100ms"
```

However at another laptop, there is absolutely no problem.

Could anyone give me some clue?

Thanks so much!

Yue

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with the IDE you're using?

Comment: Which language is it written in, C or C++?  If you are using classes or `std::string`, it is not C.

Comment: Smells like an issue in destructors; or uninitialized variables.

Comment: Works on one computer and not another? Could be a library dependency. It's also likely that the program only *looks* like it works on one computer and is being honest on the other.

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually I totally forgot the thread, hehe. I got a colleague to solve the problem. Thank you for all the answers!